# Смерть процесса

Tags: winapi, windows, delphi, процесс

День добрый, сразу к сути вопроса....

Известно:

1. хэндл на открытый процес(PROCESS_ALL_ACСESS).
2. Наименование процесса.
3. PID.

Задача:

1. Узнать выделеную процессу память(дабы не вылезти за границы отведенной памати в попытках чтения)?
2. Узнать об аварийном\нормальном завершении процесса(убили через диспечер например)?
3. Узнать его открытые соединения?

Что то зачастил я сюда с вопросами.. хоть и не находятся на них ответы...

Comment: >> Узнать его открытые соединения?

Вы сетевые соединения имеете в виду?

Узнать выделенную память напрямую я, помнится, способа не нашел, перебирал всю страницу. Правда, надобность в этом быстро отпала - не нужны мне стали сведения о выделенной памяти процесса.

>> Узнать об аварийном\нормальном завершении процесса

Этого Вы ни как не узнаете, если процесс не должен сообщать ExitCode. Если должен - то проверка на код. Убитый процесс всегда возвращает 0.

Comment: 1) да сетевые
2) хм, процес занимает в оперативке\подкачке 500мб, я пытаюсь прочесть значение по адресу 510мб.. и получаю эксцепшн в своем приложении(а если пытаюсь сделать это же из внедренной длл то эксцепшн пациента).
3) Как же мне тогда отследить можно ли читать по открытому(ранее) хенделу процеса память или он уже мертв давно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) [Nt/ZwQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  c классом SystemProcessInformation, либо проще  [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Работает в Ring3

2) Самый простой вариант [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) из драйвера. Регистрируешь свою процедуру обратного вызова

```
 VOID
(*PCREATE_PROCESS_NOTIFY_ROUTINE) (
    IN HANDLE  ParentId,
    IN HANDLE  ProcessId,
    IN BOOLEAN  Create
    );
```

И если Create==FALSE (завершение процесса)выполняешь необходимые тебе проверки. Собственно из Ring0.

GetExitCodeProcess из Ring3

3) Например как реализовано в этой программе [netstatp](http://source.sphene.net/svn/goim/trunk/net.sphene.goim.netstat/native/src/netstatp.c)

Comment: 1) GetProcessMemoryInfo Долго же?) или приложение не может уменьшить обьем выделеной памяти так просто?) т.е. если вызывать перед чтением каждой переменной - повешу систему намертво) если звать перед чтением пачки, то кто помешает освободить память во время чтения?
2) несовсем то, нужно просто проверить есть ли такой процесс, и можно ли из него читать или его уже нет, и можно сохранять результат и чистить у себя память выделеную под данные того процесса.
3)Опять таки слишком громоздко, в разы быстрей и проще перехватить создание сокета.

Спасибо за советы, как временные решения подойдут точно

Comment: Пока что не принимаю, может кто чего лучше предложет) но спасибку ткнул)